# ORACLE - How to display 3 different values from one column

Tags: oracle

I have one table with 4 types and one "value" column, I need to display 3 columns per id in a single query.
type 1= abc,type 2= def,type 3= ghi,type 4= jkl
my current query, for now display all values in a single column, I need a column per typeid, would be 4 columns with different name

```
SELECT 
 OBJECTID
,TRUNC(DATETIME + 1 / (24 * 12), 'HH24') DATETIME
,TIMEZONE
,VALUE as value
,LOADID LOADID
FROM PROD.TS_WSI_HOURLY_OBSERVATION
where typeid in(1,2,3,4);
```

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 85 |

How I need to display this kind of result:

| abc | def | ghi | jkl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 30 | 20 | 85. |
| 15 | 10 | 4 | 34. |
| 34 | 30 | 12 | 8598 |

Any idea how to do this? I need all the rows, not aggregations like max

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we usually do it:

```
SQL> with temp (gbc, id, value) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 'a', 1, 50 from dual union all
  4     select 'b', 1, 15 from dual union all
  5     select 'c', 1, 34 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'a', 2, 30 from dual union all
  8     select 'b', 2, 10 from dual union all
  9     select 'c', 2, 30 from dual union all
 10     --
 11     select 'a', 3, 20 from dual union all
 12     select 'b', 3,  4 from dual union all
 13     select 'c', 3, 12 from dual
 14    )
 15  select gbc,
 16         sum(case when id = 1 then value end) as abc,
 17         sum(case when id = 2 then value end) as def,
 18         sum(case when id = 3 then value end) as ghi,
 19         sum(case when id = 4 then value end) as jkl
 20  from temp
 21  group by gbc;

GBC        ABC        DEF        GHI        JKL
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
a           50         30         20
b           15         10          4
c           34         30         12

SQL>
```

---

Or, if I understood your query, you'd just use it as a CTE and extract desired values:

```
with temp as
  (select 
      typeid,
      objectid
     ,trunc(datetime + 1 / (24 * 12), 'HH24') datetime
     ,timezone
     ,value as value
     ,loadid loadid
   from prod.ts_wsi_hourly_observation
   where typeid in(1,2,3,4)
  )
select sum(case when typeid = 1 then value end) as abc,  
       sum(case when typeid = 2 then value end) as def,
       sum(case when typeid = 3 then value end) as ghi,
       sum(case when typeid = 4 then value end) as jkl
from temp
group by objectid;
```

Comment: Hi, I have like 300 records in this table, how to show it all without sum, because if I delete the sum statement show me just one value per record, and 3 columns null, I need all columns filled

Comment: Exactly. That's why I used SUM.

Comment: but the sum only showed one record, I need to show the 300 records, also why do you use objectid when is typeid ?

Comment: There must be something else (another column(s) you can use in SELECT column list) which won't be aggregated, but will be used to "split" the result into separate rows. That column doesn't have to be specified in SELECT, but must be used in GROUP BY clause. Why did I use OBJECTID? Because I looked at query you posted, and there's no TYPEID in its SELECT column list. Query I posted is just an **example** of how to do it; adjust it so that it fits your need (now that you know how).

Comment: I edited code I previously posted so that it includes the GBC column (short for "GroupByColumn"). Query with sample data has it in both SELECT and GROUP BY. Query based on yours contains it only in GROUP BY, where I presumed that it is OBJECTID you'll be grouping values by. If that's not it, change it to other column(s); I don't know which one(s), but you should.